# Ubuntu Server not showing in Windows

Tags: server, storage, share, samba, nas

Ubuntu server not showing in windows. I managed to get the printer working on the network with Ubuntu from my other windows computers. But now I want to have the Ubuntu server to also be a network drive for offline storage, maybe cloud storage in the future after I feel more comfortable with my security skills.

I tried installing Samba and adding wins top the hosts line in nsswitch.conf. I changed the server name made a custom group and gave permissions. Maybe I need to add the windows machine to the group I made. I tried using the GUI to share the home folder on the Ubuntu Desktop. But the machine will not show in the windows network. My windows computer is directly connected to the switch that is also directly connected to the server and the printer works fine from my windows computer. Do i need to change the smb.conf file for the interface from the loopback to the address I use to connect via xRDP? I made home directory browse able from no to yes.

Comment: Did you update ufw to let Samba ports through ?